# "Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL."

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL Server. But I've seen this with SQL Server 2017. I am creating System-Versioned tables. After I create the table, I'll create a MERGE statement to deposit data into the table (the MERGE statement will be used again to keep the table updated). Many times I will get an error message stating: *Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.* If I simply drop the table and recreate, I don't see the error again.

This doesn't happen with every table I create, but it's frequent. Until recently I have never seen this error before. Any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: I'd guess that some process... is attempting to set a non-nullable column's value to `NULL`. I know, not very clever, but with no details for reproduction that's probably the best anyone can do. In all seriousness -- `MERGE` has seen [many, many bugfixes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), and I doubt it's perfect now. Combine that with versioned tables and there's some potential for trouble. You'd need more detailed steps for reproduction before anyone could look into it, though. For all we know it's just a bug in your own statements.

Comment: It's worth noting that "I've never seen this before" does not preclude a bug in your own statements -- it wouldn't be the first time the optimizer's logic or data distribution or hardware characteristics change and expose a fundamental flaw in queries that have "always worked" up to that point, but were secretly always nondeterministic and potentially problematic. On Azure, of course, you get a front row seat to such changes.

Comment: Relevant thread on microsoft.com where a similar issue was raised: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4fbdfcc-c10e-4412-8011-2bbd3cdda5eb/merge-on-temporal-table-fails-with-attempting-to-set-a-nonnullable-columns-value-to-null?forum=sqldatabaseengine. The OP there claims: `It appears to be a defect. The only way I got around this was to just remove the index from the temporal history table.`

Comment: Another relevant thread: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/33153958--attempting-to-set-a-non-null-able-column-s-value. OP claims: `I found out that the index on the history table might be corrupt. If I rebuild the index, this error message disappears as well.`

Comment: More relevance: http://www.sqlservice.se/merge-issue-attempting-to-set-a-non-null-able-columns-value-to-null/. Claims: `When looking at the indexes of the target table, I found a non clustered index that had the same columns as the primary key index. There is no need for duplicated indexes, [...] I decided to remove the index, just to reduce the overhead.
[...] The merge statement now works! [...]`

Comment: We noticed the same issue in the last days. This seems not to be fixed in the last two years :(

I can reproduce this on an empty database:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e14b18aa4405ed1a410248c3d761231

I found also one more Azure Feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35519209-merge-not-working-when-index-created-on-temporal-t

I cannot delete the index, because its there for a reason.

What is the official way to report such a bug to Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

i have had the same problem
"The only way I got around this was to just remove the index from the temporal history table" - it was my solution

Comment: Occurred to me on sql server 2019.  This was the solution.